# Please explain this trait with a self reference

Tags: rust

I've seen this trait as a way to pass references to async functions. I don't understand it

```
trait AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>: FnOnce(Arg) -> <Self as AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>>::Fut {
    type Fut: Future<Output = <Self as AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>>::Output>;
    type Output;
}
```

I especially don't understand the super trait referencing the trait in the function return.

It looks like a lot of the trait text is to use associated types in the correct places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have a trait `AsyncSingleArgFnOnce` with a generic parameter `Arg`.

It has an associated type `Output` specifying the declared return type of the `async fn`.

It then has another associated type, `Fut`, that specifies the actual return type of the `async fn`. Remember that:

```
async fn foo() -> Bar { ... }
```

Is actually:

```
fn foo() -> impl Future<Output = Bar> { async move { ... } }
```

So `Output` is `Bar`, and `Fut` is the `impl Future`.

This associated type is constrained to be a future (`type Fut: Future<Output = ...>`) whose output type is `<Self as AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>>::Output`. `AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>` is just the trait itself; `<Self as AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>>::Output` is the fully-qualified `Output` associated type of the trait `AsyncSingleArgFnOnce` of the implementing type. That is, just the value of the associated type `Output`.

The trait has `FnOnce(Arg) -> ...` as a supertrait, that means it needs to be a function (`FnOnce`) that takes `Arg` (the generic parameter) and returns `<Self as AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>>::Fut`. Just as with `<Self as AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>>::Output`, that just means the value of the associated type `Fut`.

So we have a trait, that requires a function with a single argument and a future return type. The returned future is in the associated type `Fut`; the declared return type is in the associated type `Output`.